# Аналог nload для мониторинга загруженности диска для Ubuntu Server

Tags: ubuntu

Очень понравилось приложение nload для Ubuntu 16.04  -показывает график "загруженности сети" и среднюю скорость потока.

Хотелось бы нечто подобное для мониторинга использования файловой системы. Какая общая средняя "нагрузка" идет на SSD на сервере в реальном времени, например в МБ/c на запить и на чтение. Если еще и график будет стоить - вообще супер.

Comment: `iotop` пробовал?

Comment: спасибо. Пробовал. Но он отображает "мгновенные значения". Хотелось бы что-то усредненное видеть, скажем за 10 секунд. И графиков консольных тоже хочется.

Comment: https://www.opsdash.com/blog/disk-monitoring-linux.html